# Dynamic Named Ranges - Last Row Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I have a sheet where a lot of columns are a named range. Their ranges all begin on row 1 and end on row 100. I want to be able to easily change the last row of all the ranges. For example, I would like all the ranges to refer to the value of cell A1 determine what the last row number.

The code currently looks like this

=Sheet1!$D$1:$D$100

If cell A1’s value is 88 then then I want the code to look like this

=Sheet1!$D$1:$D$88

I’m hoping there is a simple formula I can enter to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` function to achieve this. So the edited formula will look as below.

`=Sheet1!$D$1:INDEX($D:$D,$A$1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `OFFSET()` function with `COUNTA()` to make named range till last data entry row. Try-

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$1,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$D))
```

If you want to take value from `A1` cell then you can use-

```
=INDIRECT("D1:D"&Sheet1!$A$1)
```